# Segmentation fault in C and infinite loop - self calling main function

Tags: c

Consider the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
   printf("hello"); 
   main(1, 2);
   return 0;
}
```

On executing the code I am getting a run time error (Segmentation Fault) and an output: `hello` infinite times.

I understand that a `segmentation fault` occurs when the program tries to access the area of memory that it is not allowed to access. Which line of my code is accessing memory it is not allowed to access and why?  I am hoping it is `main(1, 2)`

And how comes `hello` is printed infinite times?

Comment: You have created a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) that recurses infinitely. The segmentation fault is caused because the recursion eventually uses up available stack memory.

Comment: So having parameters of main as 1,2 has no effect?

Comment: Well, you're not using those parameters for anything, so no, it has no effect.

Comment: What exactly did you intend with this code, functionally? It really doesn't make much sense. Calling `main(1, 2)` pushes two arguments on the stack and calls `main`. `main` ignores those arguments. But every function call pushes at least the program counter on the stack, so your infinite recursion continually uses more and more stack until you venture into memory that does not belong to your app.

Comment: Which effect do you expect that arguments `(1,2)` should have? Your `main` function does not provide a prototype with any parameters.

Comment: Stack overflow. Dot com.

Answer (score 4):

Although you are allowed to call `main` from itself in C (note you are not allowed to in C++), you need to (i) ensure the parameter list is valid and, (ii) ensure you have a mechanism in place to prevent *infinite recursion*.

As you do neither of these, the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

Comment: The C99 and C11 standards allow a recursive `main` in principle, but it is discouraged

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Indeed, but how could you win an obfuscation contest without it? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1301856

Comment: @bathsheba what mechanism can i use to prevent infinite recursion?

Comment: @GirishArora: Ditch the recursion and use a `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because your main function is recursively calling itself, and giving itself too many parameters. You're also going to cause a stack overflow by recursively calling infinite times.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that a segmentation fault occurs when the program tries to access the area of memory that it is not allowed to access. Which line of my code is accessing memory it is not allowed to access and why?

To answer that question you need to understand how recursion is implemented in C and how the stack works.

[Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygK0YON10sQ). Although he doesn't tell you what happens when there is an infinite recursion, I am sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are currently implementing a recursive function main with 2 arguments ( **main(1,2)** ) , but the main you have already written has no arguments ( **main()** ) , so the recursive method will never end. Although I cannot understand what are you trying to do , its generally a bad idea to implement recursive processes on your **main** function. In the end , you will run out of memory as the stack pointer will try to access prohibited segments of memory. So your program crushes.
For future endeavours in the recursion process I suggest you to put a condition that when met the recursion will end.